# Farther object drawn in front near object (openGL)

Tags: opengl

Main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);

glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 

glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glutInitWindowPosition (700, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Result");
glutDisplayFunc(display2);  
glutReshapeFunc(reshape2);
glutMouseFunc(main_mouse);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Display2 function:

```
void display2()
{   
glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glLoadIdentity();

//Green square
glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(0.5,0.5,-1.0);
glVertex3f(0.5,1.5,-1.0);
glVertex3f(1.5,1.5,-1.0);
glVertex3f(1.5,0.5,-1.0);
glEnd();

//Red square
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,-2.0);
glVertex3f(0.0,1.0,-2.0);
glVertex3f(1.0,1.0,-2.0);
glVertex3f(1.0,0.0,-2.0);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

reshape2 function

```
void reshape2(int width, int height)
{
glViewport(0,0,width,height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

glOrtho(-3.0,3.0,-3.0,3.0,0.01,3.0);
}
```

I have problem with depth buffer in openGL. I try to draw 2 square red and green. The red one is located behind the green one. 
Red square have z value -2 while green square have z value -1. But the red square displayed at front of green square. I have enabled the depth test but still not work. What is wrong with my program?

Comment: I have not used GLUT, well ever, but... I am pretty sure you have to create a window before you can start setting GL states. Window creation is usually the point at which a context is created and/or made active... thus you have enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` before you even had a render context in which to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call any `gl*` function before you call `glutCreateWindow`, so move `glEnable` and `glDepthFunc` after it.

Every `gl` functions make calls to the context which is only created with the GLUT window. No OpenGL functions is effective before that.